# Linq to SQL vs Entity Framework

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

Cual es la diferencia entre el `SubmitChanges` de Linq y el `Add` de Entity Framework ?

```
WTablasDataContext.AfipEscalaSuss.Add(obj)

WTablasDataContext.AfipEscalaSuss.SubmitChanges(obj)
```

Comment: Hola Federico. Has mirado la documentacion de ambas para ver que hacen exactamente? Mira [ask] para mejorar la calidad de tu pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Creo que la pregunta no tiene relación con el contenido. ¿El problema es con Linq to SQL o con Entity Framework?

Comment: No hay un problema. Es saber la diferencia para saber cual usar en cada caso. O si se usa una o la otra.

Answer (score 2):

Estás mezclando dos cosas diferentes:

El `Add` en *LINQ To SQL* y *Entity Framework* añade una entidad al contexto de manera se marquen para ser insertados luego que se persistan su cambios.

`SubmitChanges` de *LINQ To SQL* y `SaveChanges` de *Entity Framework* justamente ejecutan todos los cambios pendientes en el context contra la base de datos, es decir generan el SQL correspondiente a los cambios y lo ejecutan.

> Nota: El parámetro de `SubmitChanges`de LINQ To SQL no es una entidad sino un `ConflictMode`. Este parámetro sirve para indicar que hacer en caso de conflicto. Los valores posibles son: `FailOnFirstConflict` y `ContinueOnConflict`

Answer (score 1):

Cuando ejecutas `SubmitChanges`, guardas los cambios en el contexto en la base de datos. Mientras que `Add(T entity)` agrega el objecto al track del DbContext agregandome un estado de que esta listo para ser insertaado pero no lo guarda en la base de datos sino hasta cuando se ejecuta el metodo `SaveChanges()`.

Comment: Claro, hasta que se ejecuta el SaveChanges, dentro del Using scope As New TransactionScope()

Comment: Claro,meexprese mal. Los dos homólogos serian SaveChanges para Entity y SubmitChanges para Linq.

Comment: Lo que no sé es cuando conviene usar uno u otro.

Comment: SubmitChanges() inicia una transacción y se revertirá si se produce una excepción mientras se ejecuta SubmitChanges. Mientras que SaveChanges() opera dentro de una transacción , devolverá esa transacción y lanzará una excepción si no se puede mantener ninguno de los objetos ObjectStateEntry

Comment: Pero ninguna de las dos llega a grabar algo si se produce una exception ?
Por lo que decís, SaveChanges estando dentro de la transacción algo llega a grabar. 
Creo que ambos se ejecutan en la RAM si es que se produce una exception, ambos abandonan el proceso no ?

Comment: Si. La diferencia es que SubmitChanges() no hara rollback de los objetos que han sido trackeados en memoria en caso de error mientras que SaveChanges() si.